# Changing the resources key from inside resources block in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have routes defined in the following manner with Rails resources:

```
resources :objects do
  get 'action', to: 'controller#action'
end
```

Does Rails provide a way of changing the param key from `object_id` to something else, such as `parent_id` for only the nested action?

I know the `param` option would allow me to change it for all resources:

```
resources :objects, param: 'parent_id'
  get 'action', to: 'controller#action'
end
```

But I'm interested only in changing it for the nested action. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Either of :

1) `resources :objects, param: :parent_id`

2) in app/models/objects

```
def to_param
  parent_id
end
```

should work

Comment: But what if I want the key to be `object_id` for everything but the nested get action? I would like it to produce `objects/:parent_id/action`.